# Stream webcam video (no audio) to a widget in Qt5

Tags: camera, pyqt, webcam, qt5, v4l2

From the documentation of Qt5 I get it that there are many widgets and classes that deal with camera input. On the other hand the documentation reads alot like intended for mobile phone cameras or even real cameras. With a viewfinder, record and snapshot buttons etc.

All I want is a widget inside my desktop Qt5 program that lets me see the video stream of my webcam (/dev/video0, v4l2). All parameters controlled via the code. Resolution, brightness and whatever the camera supports. No GUI elements.

Minimal but working code examples are appreciated. Either C++/Qt5 or pyqt5. But a hint which classes I should use in which connection would be a start as well.

Thank you very much!

P.S. Please, no answers that consists only(!) of a link to a documentation page as if that was self-explenatory. There is a camera example but did not help me much. Otherwise I would not have to ask here.

Answer (score 3):

Documentation like this http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtmultimediawidgets-camera-example.html is really all you need.

The minimal working example:
(Tested on ubuntu with pseye camera. If this is only camera in system, you don't have to specify device path )

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"


#include <QCamera>
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QVideoWidget>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    camera = new QCamera(this);
    videoWidget = new QVideoWidget();
    ui->mainLayout->addWidget(videoWidget);

    camera->setViewfinder(videoWidget);
    camera->start();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: just add a formLayout to the MainWindow is designer and name it mainLayout.  Also add multimedia and multimediawidget to QT += and everything works fine.

Comment: Be wary that if you get a low quality stream, low FPS or any of the like, that this might be due to the default settings and stream the video widget is requesting from the webcam. The Qt5 Camera example includes a drop-down list that lets you select settings like the stream codec and FPS. Find out the specs and available streams of your webcam with `v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext` if you're using video4linux2.